# Testing performance of Java project in Eclipse using VisualJVM

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, jvm

I aim to do some timing/memory tests on a Java application that is runned via Eclipse.
After browsing the Web, I have found the "Visual JVM" that can be considered as a fine tool for prifiling the application. Isn't?
So, my question is how can I download and use it in Eclipse? are there some tutorials/codes that guide me?

Thnx for Your prompt answers that I really need.

Cheers,
Sana.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/best-kept-secret-jdk-visualvm) is a tutorial for using VisualVM in various IDEs; including Eclipse.

You can download the VisualVM launcher [here](http://java.net/projects/visualvm/content/eclipse-launcher.html). VisualVM is actually in your JDK, and can be run as a stand-alone (separate from Eclipse) program from there.

Comment: Thanx LFA for Your answer, but I read that I can download the VM directly as a plugin from Eclipse, so what's the difference between running it within Eclipse or stand-alone? what's better?

Comment: Using VisualVM as a stand-alone program requires less setup time that using it in Eclipse, however it also requires more time for each run (since you have to locate the directory of your JDK). Basically, if you are only using VisualJVM a few times, don't bother integrating it with your IDE and vise-versa.

Comment: 1000 thanx LFA. A last question: should I add some codes or somethings similar into my java-project to link with the VisualVM?

Comment: No, you should not need to modify your code for it to work with VisualVM.